# Jquery acting different on mobile compared to PC, with the same code

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

The problem is in the website I am developing

http://balticpremier.sem.lv/en/

(https://www.virustotal.com/#/url/e2f05f0f4d6fde378f3f784c8c331849caef1e556fb1b173e4ac2f5ba521405c/detection)

Scroll to the bottom and see the Our delivered products section. It is supposed to expand on hover and click, which it does without problem on PC. However, when it is visited through phone, on click, it does the fade effect and doesn't have the correct logic.

This is the only JS that affects this part is here:

```
$('.deliveredCategory').on('click mouseenter mouseleave', function () {
    $(this).find(".expandableClient").toggle();
    $(this).find('.plus-minus-toggle').toggleClass('collapsed');
    $(this).find('.dotHide').toggle();
});
```

Help appreciated!!

EDIT: Forgot to say that fade effect is not a part of the code, and only happens on mobile. Is this how toggle(); is interpreted on mobile? Either way, on mobile I also can't close it after it has been expanded. Really weird.

Comment: My guess would be that the event is being fired multiple times on a mobile device - probably all three events, hence nothing appears to be changed.

Comment: At what mobile device and what browser does the fade effect happens?

Comment: use touch events.

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski The effect happens on Chrome, Android. Phone is Oneplus 5

Comment: @NKNz hmm, that's weird. On my phone (Nokia x) opera browser it is correct. Also on desktop in chrome devtools when I enter mobile mode it is correct. I tested it even on firefox mobile mode and there it also works properly.

Comment: @NKNz it's because the event is fired 2 times on touch devices (both click and mouseenter). Try using `$('.deliveredCategory').on('click hover' .....` instead

Comment: @Chri.s By hover you mean mouseover? Because mouseover is glitchy with elements with text in it. I'd rather use mouseenter and mouseleave. But the problem is that it has a fade effect which isn't a part of the code, nor any library I use.

Comment: @NKNz no I actually mean the `hover` property in jQuery. You can see the different behaviours here: https://jsfiddle.net/gt3baxr3/4/ (also added a `mouseover` for you to see the difference). Try it on a touch device though. On click on a touch device a combination of `click mouseover` fires 3 times, combination of `click mouseenter mouseleave` fires 2 times and combination of `click hover` fires 1 time.

Comment: But `hover` isn't triggered on desktop too so I guess that's not the way to do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found the solution. I really hope it satisfies yopu, if not, then sorry :)

So you can check whether there the device is a touch device and if so unbind mouseover event. Or any other event you want to.

```js
var num = 0;
$(".testDiv").on("click mouseover", function() {
  num++;
  $(".testDiv").text(num)
});
if (!!('ontouchstart' in window)) { //check for touch device
  $('.cc').unbind('mouseover');
}
```

```css
.testDiv {
  background: lightgreen;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Div below uses "click mouseover"</span>
<div class="testDiv">
  <p>
    Initial text to test whether hovering this works properly. Initial text to test whether hovering this works properly.
  </p>
</div>
```

I hope this is what you wanted.

Regards, KJ

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the site I am working on has Cloudflare connected and it cached a part of my JS code before, which explains the problems I am having. I contacted the host manager, they flushed the cache and it works again.

Thank you all for answers.

Comment: I can only accept it as an answer after 2 days. New account.

Comment: Ok, I see :) I too have a new account, but I didn't know about that :)